How to modify a jsonb variable without jsonb_set?
I have a jsonb variable inside a loop that I want to update, each time I want to update a row I execute a sql update using jsonb_set, the same row can be updated thousands of times depending on the scenario, because the jsonb cell can hold a lot of data.
The execution time to update thousands of records takes around 20 minutes with the code below which is a plpglsql function.
In some scenarios the execution time can go up to 4 hours, so I figure out that the slowness culprit is nothing that the jsonb_set since the json I want to update can hold up to 260kb of data.
So I have changed my solution and used another pl language which is plv8 to go around the problem and avoid sql updates with jsonb_set, it was a huge success, I succeeded to decrease the exec time from 4 hours to a couple of minutes.
But my guts feeling tells me that I can do the same with plpqsql and I want to avoid using plv8 (personal choice) for these kind of operations.
Is there any operator, function,  solution that I can use to solve this problem?
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "public"."bulk_price_import_cat_mat"()
 AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
    cpt INT := 0;
BEGIN



          FOR rec IN
                    select * from feuil1,
                (
                        SELECT 
                                id,
                                key AS m,
                                obj_ordinality - 1 AS rank,
                                (obj->>'plu')::VARCHAR AS plu,
                                (obj->>'price')::numeric AS price
                        FROM 
                                (select id, price from shop_config where config_target = 'product' and price_type = 'category_matrix' and shop_id in (SELECT id FROM shop WHERE client_id = 'e44c0df8-c5c1-4c84-92de-792a3e7ffd40')) sc,
                                jsonb_each(sc.price) AS kv,
                                jsonb_array_elements(kv.value) WITH ORDINALITY AS obj(obj, obj_ordinality)
                            
                                
                )    mat
                    
                where feuil1.plu = mat.plu and feuil1.computed_plu = false
                    

                
        LOOP
            IF MOD(cpt, 10000) = 0 THEN
                COMMIT; -- Commit every 10000 iterations
                RAISE NOTICE 'shop_config matrix price::commit %', cpt;
            END IF;
                        
                        update shop_config  
                        set price = jsonb_set(
                                                price::jsonb, 
                                                concat('{', rec.m, ',' , rec.rank, ', price}')::text[],
                                                 rec.prix::jsonb)
                                                 where id = rec.id;
                        cpt := cpt + 1;
                        
           
        END LOOP;

            
    RAISE NOTICE 'Update into shop_config done for all plu %', cpt;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql


Advice: Don't use a LOOP for data sets, it makes your code slow.

If that's your attempt at working around update limit of one undetermined FROM row per query, you can work out the sum of required updates, a squashed/final/cumulative update in a plain SQL recursive query: 1, 2. It's typically faster than a looped update issued from a PL/pgSQL block. Or, you can ditch json and normalise your structure.

For a serious question, you need to provide your Postgres version, and exact definitions of the (relevant parts of) tables shop, shop_config and feuil1 (CREATE TABLE scripts!). This cast price::jsonb is suspicious to say the least. Plus cardinalities for each table. " ... the jsonb cell can hold a lot of data." is too unspecific. Min / max / avg size of the column & number of keys would be more helpful. And describe the general purpose of the function in non-technical terms. Show minimal sample values and the desired result.

This function can certainly be optimized in multiple ways.
